# проблемы при подключении внешнего сетевого адаптера в VB на Kali Linux

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

1. я скачал VB и установил туда Kali Linux
2. подключил внешний сетевой адаптер к компьютеру
3. установил драйвера на основную OC, на основной OC он заработал
4. добавил устройство в USB [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
6. при подключении устройства к Kali linux, адаптер перестает работать на обычном устройстве , но при это не подключается к виртуальной машине
7. итог: не выводит wlan [image: введите сюда описание изображения]